# Can we subtract an inequality from the same inequality, and if so, does that mean $0<0$ is a true statement?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

Consider the inequality $1<3$.

Are we allowed to subtract the the same inequality from the above inequality?

If so we get $0<0$.

Is $0<0$ true?

Comment: You have proven that subtracting inequalities is not a valid operation, as it leads to the  specific falsehood $0<0$.

Comment: Perhaps the real question is "why can we add inequalities"?  Suppose you take as fact that if $x<y$ then we can add any number $w$ to both sides to conclude $x+w<y+w$.  Homework: Use this fact to prove that if $a<b$ and $c<d$ then we can conclude $a+c<b+d$.

Answer (score 2):

If we define what it means to subtract inequalities in terms of addition and multiplication, it becomes obvious why we cannot subtract two inequalities and expect the result to hold.

Suppose we have the following inequalities:

$$\begin{align}
a&<b & &(1)\\
c&<d & &(2)
\end{align}$$

To subtract these inequalities, what we actually do is to first negate the inequalities, and second add them.

Subtracting naively, we get:

$$\begin{align}
a&<b & &(1)\\
-c&<-d & &(*)\\
\hline a-c&<b-d & &(3)
\end{align}$$

But notice that when we negated $(2)$ to get $(*)$, we should have flipped the inequality. In fact, if $(2)$ is true, then $(*)$ cannot be true. Thus $(3)$ does not follow from $(1)$ and $(2)$, so inequality subtraction does not work, as you have defined it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add 2 inequalities, but you cannot subtract 2 inequalities.

1 < 2

0 < 3

If you subtract them, you get 1 < -1 which is definitely false.

Comment: Is there a way to trace the reason that we can't subtract inequalities to some fundamental basic quality or axiom about numbers?

Comment: If I have less apples than you, and then someone comes along and adds a certain amount of apples to me, and an even bigger amount to you, then obviously I still have less apples than you. This means we can add inequalities. But if I have less apples than you and then someone comes and takes $10$ of your apples then it's no longer correct that I necessarily have less apples than you. This shows you can't add the correct inequality $0<10$ to both sides of $a<b$ and expect to necessarily get another correct inequality.

Answer (score 1):

If you have

- $a < b$ and
- $c > d$

then you cannot say from this whether $a+c<b+d$ or $a+c>b+d$ or $a+c=b+d$, and any of these three could be the case.

If you then have

- $a < b$ and
- $e < f$

then, letting $c=-e$ and $d=-f$ and noting that this then implies implies $c>d$, so $a-e=a+c$ and $b-f=b+d$,

you therefore cannot say from this whether $a-e<b-f$ or $a-e>b-f$ or $a-e=b-f$ in exactly the same way as before, and any of these three could be the case.